# mod_rewrite: pass all requests to query string

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been struggling with this for hours and have now seen one 500 error too many! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I need a RewriteRule that will pass any and all requests to a query string.

```
RewriteRule ^/* anything */$ index.php?page=$1
```

At one point I kind of had this working but the problem was that pages such as **home.php** could still be accessed directly without being rewritten as **index.php?page=home.php**

I would like even the most obscure requests to be dealt with in this way, e.g.

```
domain.com/jdhjf.php/383_/index.php.html
```

...would be rewritten as...

```
 domain.com/index.php?page=jdhjf.php/383_/index.php.html
```

Also, if you could make it force both **https://** and **www.** as well then you would really make my week!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From httpd reference manual. This might do the job. L = Last Rule, QSA Query String Append.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```